# What is the proper procedure for adding FlutterFire to the iOS portion of a Flutter plugin? (not an app - a plugin)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-plugin

I know that for apps, the GoogleService-Info.plist file needs to be added to Runner in Xcode by doing "Add files to Runner". I have done the same, but for my plugin's Pods by doing "Add files to Pods". However, when running my example app, Xcode loses the GoogleService-Info.plist file and so the call `await Firebase.initializeApp()` fails.

As an aside, for Android everything is working nicely - the plugin can initialize Firebase successfully.

What is the correct procedure for making sure that the GoogleService-Info.plist file gets added to the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make it work for iOS is to include the plist as a resource file in the plugin podspec like so:

1. Place the plist in `ios/Assets`
2. Add the line `s.resources = 'Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist'` to the podspec